# Determine volume location by understanding Windows symbolic link name

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I need to figure out the location pointed to by a Windows symbolic link in order to troubleshoot something wrong with the folder or files located there.  It's of the form:  C:?\Volume{5c286810-f966-...}

Is there a utility to do this, or is this supposed to be looked up in the registry?

Comment: I don't know if there's a more official way, but the `mountvol` program (with no arguments) lists volume names and usually logical drives.

Comment: try WinObj: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys. Apparently I'm too new to upvote comments or select answers (???)  
  
Dave:  issuing the mountvol command with no arguments did not work for me, at least not in Windows Server 2012 R2. It takes that as a syntax error and gives me the help content.  
  
MagicAndre: I was able to find a reference to the volume in WinObj, in the Global?? container. The properties on the volume list it as \Device\HarddiskVolume6 which I think is enough to point me in the right direction where I need to troubleshoot my real issue.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Grrrr... still trying to get used to mini-Markdown.  @dave_thompson_085 - mountvol with no arguments doesn't work in Win2012 R2.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - thanks; I cannot yet upvote, but I was able to use WinObj to find the volume reference and get info.  Had to browse containers a bit, but it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [Winobj](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) from the [Microsoft Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062).

Under `GLOBAL??` you see which VOLUME is linked to which HDD/CDROM this volume is linked.